# How to visualize loss and accuracy the best?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, mnist

I wrote a convolutional neural network in tensorflow to perform on the mnist dataset. Everything works just fine, but i want to visualize the model in tensorboard. How am i gonna do it? Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 200000
batch_size = 128
display_step = 10

# Network Parameters
n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)


# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                  padding='SAME')


# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Apply Dropout
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Construct model
pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, 
labels=y))
optimizer = 
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                   keep_prob: dropout})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y,
                                                             keep_prob: 1.})
            print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 256 mnist test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                      y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                      keep_prob: 1.}))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: sorry i mean the code how to visualize it in tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create summary scalars and operation:

```
cost = tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)
accuracy = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
train_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([cost,accuracy])
```

Do writer:

```
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir+'/train',
                                        graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

Use it in session run and write the summary:

```
loss, acc, summary = sess.run([cost, accuracy, train_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x,y: batch_y,keep_prob: 1.})
train_writer.add_summary(train_summary_str, step)
```

Later, use tensorboard (point to folder you're writing summary) to visualize graphs of loss and accuracy.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: could you send me my whole code, with build in your code? I'm getting some very weird errors...

Comment: WOW dude i really got it with some improvement to my code!! Thank you so much, you really helped me out!!!!